# Circle Radius from its center and a point on it

Tags: objective-c, math, trigonometry

I am trying to find the radius of a circle using only its center (origin coordinates are known) and a point on it. how can I do this? I am using objective C language.

Comment: That's more a maths problem than a coding issue...

Answer (score 3):

Use this method

```
    -(float)radiusFromCenter:(CGPoint)center andPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
     return sqrt(pow(center.x-point.x,2)+pow(center.y-point.y,2));
}
```